# Using .apply vs subsets

Tags: pandas, performance

As far as I know using .apply() in pandas is rather inefficient because it isn't vectorized.
I have a bunch of relatively normal operations like addition or multiplication which I want to do differently depending on the content of certain columns.

The central question is what are the advantages and disadvantages of the two below code snippets:

```py
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: x/df['col'].max() if x < 1000 else x)

# or 

df.loc[df['col']<1000,'col'] = df["col"]/df['col'].max()
```

I've noticed that the first is slower but I've seen it recommended a lot and I sometimes get slice errors for the second version so was hesitant to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `loc` to set a subset on the LHS, you should also subset on the RHS so it's explicit. This will avoid errors in cases where the index might be duplicated.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(997,1003)})

m = df['col'].lt(1000)
df.loc[m, 'col'] = df.loc[m, 'col']/df['col'].max()
#           col
#0     0.995010
#1     0.996008
#2     0.997006
#3  1000.000000
#4  1001.000000
#5  1002.000000
```

---

Alternatively, use `np.where` for an `if-else` clause:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(997,1003)})
df['col'] = np.where(df['col'].lt(1000), df['col']/df['col'].max(), df['col'])
```

---

In terms of using `apply` [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code) has much more thorough answers. Particularly, see @jpp's answer. You may have have seen `.apply` suggested for a groupby object, or to perform column-wise calculations for a narrow DataFrame, which are typically fine.